# HTML select option selected in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Are there any examples how to use Bootstrap for HTML *select option selected* like in the example below?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/id/" method="get">
<p>Input 
  <select name="TestID">

      <option selected value="1">Test1</option>

      <option selected value="2">Test2</option>

  </select>
  <br />
</p>
  position:<input type="number" name="startpos" value="1000" />
  <input type="submit" name="testsubmit" value="GO!"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, multple select? Bootstrap doesn't have any effect the select.. it would work the same as a plain old HTML select

Comment: `http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/` Try this. bootstrap multiselect plugin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this multiselect plugin : http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

```
<!-- Include Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery: -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include the plugin's CSS and JS: -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>

<!-- Build your select: -->
<select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
<option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
<option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
<option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
<option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
<option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
<option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>

<!-- Initialize the plugin: -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.multiselect').multiselect();
});
</script>
```